# Am I using GraphQL incorrectly? I don't know how it sends me back data

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

So I'm working on a project that wants me to use GraphQL  to create my API. I'm also using NodeJS and Express. Normally I'd just set up an endpoint in express and call it with axios from the client side. Inside the endpoint on the server, I could then take the information from req.body and do with it what I want. Where would I be able to manipulate the data in that same way using GraphQL? It feels like all I'm doing is querying for data instead of manipulating it and sending it back like I want to.

Here's what I have:

Schema graphql:

```js
import GraphQLDate from 'graphql-date';

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = require('graphql');


const SecretMessage = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'secretMessage',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    message: { type: GraphQLString },
    expirDate: { type: GraphQLDate },
  }),
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    secretMessage: {
      type: SecretMessage,
      args: {
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parVal, args) {
        return `${args.name}test`;
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
});
```

My node server:

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const config = require('../webpack.config.js');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema.js');


const compiler = webpack(config);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('css'));
app.use(express.static('images'));

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
  schema,
  graphiql: true,
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/src', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('#', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Pound hashtag works');
});

app.post('passphrase', (req, res) => {
  console.log('passphrase tag works');
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/src', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('This is the express error: ', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Express is listening on port: ', port);
  }
});
```

```js
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/graphql',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        query: `secretMessage(name: "${this.state.name}") {name}`,
      }),
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log('This is the response from the axios call: ', response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('This is the error from the main axios call: ', error);
    });
```

When I make an axios post call to /graphql, i just get a 400 bad request error.

The 'test' thing next to the string interpolation was me just trying to see if I could manipulate what data is there. I didn't know how to test it in postman though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `express-graphql` or similar middleware, your GraphQL endpoint will be accessable using both POST and GET requests.

**Using POST:**

1. Change the request URL to match your server's GraphQL endpoint
2. Make sure the method for the request is POST, not GET
3. Under `Body`, select `x-www-form-urlencoded`
4. Add `query` as a `key` and your entire query string as the `value`
5. If you have any variables, add a `variables` key and include them as the `value` (they'll need to be correctly-formatted JSON).

**Using GET:**

1. Change the request URL to match your server's GraphQL endpoint
2. Make sure the method for the request is GET
3. Add `query` as a `key` and your entire query string as the `value` under `Params`
4. If you have any variables, add a `variables` parameter and include them as the `value` (they'll need to be correctly-formatted JSON).

**Alternatively...**

If you're building a GraphQL server, you may find it much easier to expose a Graph *i* QL endpoint for testing your queries. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql).

[image]

It's baked into both `graphql-server-express` (see docs [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/graphiql.html#graphiqlExpress)) and `express-graphql` (docs [here](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options)).

**Edit:** As far as manipulating the data from your request: yes, the resolver functions are where you can read your request and specify the data being returned. However, each `resolve()` function is tied to a specific field, which returns a particular type. Queries and mutations are themselves nothing more than fields on a "Root Query" or "Root Mutation" type, which is why they also have resolve functions.

Your `secretMessage` query resolves to a type of `secretMessage`, but you're resolving it to a String. If you try to run that query, it will always return null as a result. Instead, if you want it to return an object with a name property that you modify according to the argument you pass in, you can do this:

```
resolve(parVal, args) {
  return { name: `${args.name}test` };
},
```

Now, if you execute a query like:

```
query MyQuery {
  secretMessage(name: "John") {
    name
  }
}
```

You should get back:

```
{
  "data": {
    "secretMessage": {
      "name": "Johntest"
    }
  }
}
```

You could also specify a resolver for your `name` field that would achieve the same effect. How and when to utilize resolvers depends on what you're trying to achieve. A more detailed explanation is outside the scope of this question, but I would encourage you to dig into the official docs and to get a better understanding of how resolvers work. You can then ask follow up questions on here (if they haven't already been asked!).

Comment: yeah currently i'm using express-graphql and I have a server running node. I'll put that into the question too in an edit.

Comment: See my edit for some additional suggestions. Make sure you're formatting your axios request correctly. It should look something like:     
    axios({
      method:   'POST'
      url: 'yoururlhere',
      headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      data:     JSON.stringify({query}),
    })
where `query` is your complete query string.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your help has definitely gotten me further. I am still getting a bad request on an axios post. I've edited my original post to include it. Again I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You need to include the `Content-Type` header, like I showed above, otherwise your body parser middleware won't know it needs to do any parsing. Also, your query string is not formatted correctly -- you need to wrap it in curly braces